# What is the best way to create strongly typed LINQ queries from some given strings, via reflection

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, reflection, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5, unit of work, and repository pattern. 
I want to define some limitations on accessing data for specified users. 
In database I've designed a table to keep my entity names and their properties which is called EntityProperties, and another table to keep the values of those properties which is called PropertyValues, and each EntityProperty has one or more PropertyValues.
In business layer when user requests data, if any limitation is defined for him, some conditions should be added to the linq statement. What I do is to get the list of entity names and their propeties and values by 'userId', then I add some 'Where' clause to the linq query. 
However, the entity names and their properties are of type "String", thus I should use Reflection to manage them.
But I don't know this part, and I don't know how to create LINQ where clause from a given set of condition strings. 
For example, let's suppose that a user requests the list orders, and user id is 5. I first query those access limitation tables, and the result is:

"Order", "Id", "74"

"Order", "Id", "77"

"Order", "Id", "115"

It means that this user should only see these three orders, while in Orders table, we have more orders.
So, if I want to use a LINQ query to get orders, like:

```
var orders = from order in Context.Orders
```

I need to turn it into something like:

```
var orders = from order in Context.Orders
```

// where order id should be in 74,77,115

However, getting to Order entity and Id property from "Order" and "Id" strings requires reflection. Thus two questions:

What is the best way to get strongly typed from strings?
Is there a better way for me to do this, with better performance?

Comment: What kind of limitations would you have in base ? You show a `Contains` on an `int` field. But will you have other kind of limitations ?

Comment: Any limitation on any property for example: user with id 5 just allowed to access to orders that their price equal to "1200"

Comment: Ok. And how would that one be represented in your limitation table ?

Comment: for example 'userId': 5 just access to orders that their price equal to "1500" and "1200"
in "EntityProperties" table => 
record1 { Id: 1 , userId:  5 , entityName: "Order" , property: "Price" }
in "PropertyValues" table =>  
record1 { Id: 1 , EntityPropertiesId: 1 , value: "1500" }
record2 { Id: 2 , EntityPropertiesId: 1 , value: "1200" }

Comment: Ok, but you have just "equality" comparison ? No case like `user 5 can access Products which have a name starting with 'a'`, or `user 5 can access orders with a price SMALLER than 1500`

Comment: yes you are right, in my project "equality" is enough. for first step it's OK then I will extend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. With the comments, we might go for something like that (assuming you have a navigation property in `EntityProperties` table, which is a collection of `PropertyValues`, and named `PropertyValueList` (if you don't have, just do a join instead of using `Include`).

Here is some sample code, really rustic, **working only with Int32 properties**, but this might be the start of a solution.

You may also look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)...

Anyway

I use an "intermediate class" Filter.

```
public class Filter
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public List<string> Values { get; set; }
    }
```

Then an helper class, which will return an `IQueryable<T>`, but... filtered

```
public static class FilterHelper {

    public static IQueryable<T> Filter(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Context context, int userId) {
        var entityName = typeof(T).Name;
        //get all filters for the current entity by userId, Select the needed values as a `List<Filter>()`
        //this could be done out of this method and used as a parameter
        var filters = context.EntityProperties
                      .Where(m => m.entityName == entityName && m.userId = userId)
                      .Include(m => m.PropertyValueList)
                      .Select(m => new Filter {
                          PropertyName = m.property,
                          Values = m.PropertyValueList.Select(x => x.value).ToList()
                      })
                      .ToList();

        //build the expression
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");

        var member = GetContains( filters.First(), parameter);
        member = filters.Skip(1).Aggregate(member, (current, filter) => Expression.And(current, GetContains(filter, parameter)));
        //the final predicate
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(member, new[] { parameter });
        //use Where with the final predicate on your Queryable
        return queryable.Where(lambda);
    }

//this will build the "Contains" part
private static Expression GetContains(Filter filter, Expression expression)
    {
        Expression member = expression;
        member = Expression.Property(member, filter.PropertyName);
        var values = filter.Values.Select(m => Convert.ToInt32(m));

        var containsMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(
            method => method.Name == "Contains"
                      && method.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                      && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                      .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(int) });
        member = Expression.Call(containsMethod, Expression.Constant(values), member);
        return member;
    }
}
```

usage

```
var orders = from order in Context.Orders
             select order;

var filteredOrders = orders.Filter(Context, 1);//where 1 is a userId
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer depends on whether you are happy to alter your access model slightly. I've got a similar situation in an application that I have written and personally I don't like the idea of having to rely on my calling code to correctly filter out the records based on the users authentication.

My approach was to use an OData service pattern to call into my Entity Framework, each of the repositories are exposed via OData independently.

An OData (WCFDataService) has QueryInterceptors which perform on the fly filtering of your data when a query is made. Thus if you asked the OData repository for context.Orders(o => o.Id) you'd only see the orders that that user was permitted to see with no additional clauses.

A good link to the basics is found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx) but it requires some work to manage the calling user and provide the filtering that you may require. You can provide the query interceptor at every record level.

Comment: I've just re-read your question and the issue with strings hasn't been addressed here. Although I will leave this answer up as a suggestion on how to perform the filtering based on the user.